# How to solve a Read Time Out Error

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

I get a "Read Timed Out" error at order checkout, everytime users use card payment gateway. Payment is well processed but the order is not generated, or sent to the user. Error has started after an update to a SSH-256 new key.

Gateway provider is Redsys, and url of error is .../redsys/index/notify

Comment: My system.log and exception.log files do not have any information on it, maybe because a proper permissions issue.